# Why does the Flickr API not let me name my own callback function for a JSONP request? Am I viewing this right?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, flickr

It appears that when [I use my own callback function](http://jsfiddle.net/RS3PN/2/) via JSONP, Flickr wraps the JSON with its own function name called `jsonFlickrFeed`.  And if I type the url/src directly on the browser, [I do see that it's indeed wrapped.](http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat+pic+%22&tagmode=any&format=json)

Does this mean I'm supposed to name my function to `jsonFlickrFeed`?  I thought when using JSONP, we get to name our own functions?

P.S.  I've browsed the site for answers, but I couldn't [find any direct answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019080/jsonp-not-finding-my-function)  The only answer I found was that someone **did** use `jsonFlickrFeed` as [the callback function name](http://jsfiddle.net/Braulio/vDr36/); however, being forced to use the name is what I want clarification on.

I'm also using javascript without jquery.

Comment: @remus looks well documented to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [Flickr documentation](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html) under the callback section it says if you want to specify the callback you need to set `jsoncallback` to the value you want.  They do not follow the pattern of "callback" like most sites use.

> **Callback Function**
>
> If you just want the raw JSON, with no function wrapper, add the
>   parameter nojsoncallback with a value of 1 to your request.
>
> To define your own callback function name, add the parameter
>   jsoncallback with your desired name as the value.
>
> ```
> nojsoncallback=1  -> {...}
> jsoncallback=wooYay   -> wooYay({...});
> ```

http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat+pic+%22&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=xxx

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I already looked on the documentation long and hard.  But alas, it wasn't long and hard enough. Thanks again.